# How do you prove the infimum and supremum?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $S$ is nonempty and bounded above. Show that the set:

$$
-S:= \{-x \mid x \in S\}
$$

is bounded below and that $\inf(-S) = -\sup(S)$.

Comment: Hint: $a\ge b\iff -a\le -b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=\sup(S)$. Then, for all $x\in S$ we have $M\geq x$ and for all $\epsilon> 0$ there is $x\in S$ with $x>M-\epsilon$.

Now, the two conditions above imply that, $-M$ satisfies that for all $-x\in -S$ we have $-M\leq -x$. Also, for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $-x\in -S$ such that $-x<-M+\epsilon$, as this follows from the inequality $x>M-\epsilon$ above, for the same $x\in S$.

This is the definition of infimum. Therefore, $-M=\inf(-S)$.